# Binary Adding Large Char arrays?

Tags: c, encryption, binary, char, hex

so i have an array of 16 char's defined as follows..

```
char CBlock[16];
```

in my program, I'm implementing CTR mode encryption (not really important, just saying), and CBlock gets initialized to a random 128-bit hex value. What my program needs to do is increment this block by 1 a number of times while it loops over a message block doing encryption. i.e.

```
for (i = 0; i < SOME_BIG_NUMBER; i++){
    CBlock = CBlock + 1; /*i know this isn't legal*/
    /*do some stuff*/
}
```

is there an easy way to do this addition? is there a way i can simply treat CBlock as one contiguous data block? or do i have to manually implement binary (hex) addition with carry's etc..

EDIT: sorry the CBlock declaration was wrong.

Comment: That's not an array of 16 chars, thats an array of 16 strings...

Comment: that was just a typo on my part. just fixed the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can implement the addition yourself by keeping track of the carries.

```
unsigned char CBlock[16]; /* unsigned char is assumed to be at least an 8 bit type. */
/* Increment CBlock by 1. */

int carry = 1;
int i;

for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
    int sum = CBlock[i] + carry;
    CBlock[i] = (unsigned char) (sum & 0xff);
    carry = sum >> 8;
    if (carry == 0) {
        break;
    }
}

/* if (carry > 0) { we have overflowed} */
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your version of C have native 128 bit numbers, `int128`?  Otherwise perhaps try making your 128 bit block from two `int64`s.  That would reduce the carry problem by a large factor.

Answer (score 0):

C does not have intrinsic support for data types larger than the machine registers on (most) microprocessors.

While 128 bits is becoming "close", it's still not a type commonly supported. So your best bet is to either use an existing "bignum" library, or code your own.

If you *only* need to increment it, that's not too hard to do yourself. For this special case, you could perhaps just use a pair of `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that `SOME_BIG_NUMBER` is small enough to fit in a `uint64_t`, and that your system is little endian (which it almost certainly is), then you can just do:

```
*(uint64_t *)&CBlock += 1;
```

or

```
*(uint64_t *)&CBlock = i;
```